# Unicode Error using JSON

Tags: python, json, unicode

I know there have been similar questions posted but I think the issue I'm having is slightly different compared to them. Please bear with me; I have only started using Python 4 months ago and I'm sure my immaturity shows!

I am writing a program that displays LinkedIn data from a CSV file using the Protovis plugin in a dendrogram. The plugin is set up correctly as far as I can see and this is all based off of O'Reilly's Mining the Social Web. However, when I run my code in IDLE, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Envy 15/Desktop/MASIDendo", line 115, in <module>
    html = open(HTML_TEMPLATE).read() % (json.dumps(json_output),)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 17: invalid start `byte`
```

Now as I understand it, the reason for the Unicode error is that there is a non-Unicode character in one of my filenames, however I have checked them and that's not the case. The part of my code it's pointing to is:

```
html = open(HTML_TEMPLATE).read() % (json.dumps(json_output),)
f = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'out', OUT), 'w')
f.write(html)
f.close()

print 'Data file written to: %s' % f.name

# Open up the web page in your browser

webbrowser.open('file://' + f.name)
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: The first line of your snippet is trying to do too much - creating the JSON, loading the template, and iterpolating the values to create the final HTML. Split these up into separate steps and you'll be more likely to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your bases, validate the content of json_data, use repr() or pprint.pprint().

str and unicode objects have methods encode and decode that accept errors argument, like this: `"\x66\x89".decode("utf-8", "replace")`

json.dumps encodes data into json, it is strange that you pass it `json_output` as input.

Comment: I cede to your wisdom, sir :)

Comment: @Dima Tisnek and then, how should we debug the JSON file after knowing which characters are problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `json_output` object has a string in it that's not unicode or unicode-encodable.  It's not the filename that's a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much you two! qarma's suggestion was better; I stuck in a print repr(json_output) and it gave me all the non-unicode characters that were in my data.